xLSTM parallel computation - mismatch in dimensions
In this recent paper, a new architecture is proposed, called xLSTM. I've implemented the sequential version in PyTorch, but it's slower than I would like, so I'm now implementing the parallel version that's explained in the appendix (page 25-26). I feel like this page might contain a mistake, or maybe I'm missing something, so I wanted to check here.
The issue is as follows. We consider an input sequence $X\in\mathbb{R}^{T\times d}$ and we obtain two matrices $F, I\in\mathbb{R}^{T\times T}$ (see the paper for details), which combine into $D\in\mathbb{R}^{T\times T}$. All well and good. Now, it is stated that $Q, K, V\in\mathbb{R}^{T\times d}$. I believe this should be $\mathbb{R}^{T\times e}$ where $e$ denotes the embedding dimension, but that is not the main source of confusion. The point is that we have the equation $C=QK^T\odot D$ in the paper, and subsequently, $H$ is obtained as $CV$. But $QK^T\in \mathbb{R}^{T\times e\times e}$, which makes sense since this is a sequence of linear transformations which will transform the sequence $V\in\mathbb{R}^{T\times e}$. But then the dimensions of $QK^T$ do not match those of $D$, so the equation $QK^T\odot D$ does not make sense to me.
Have I missed something here, or is there an issue with the equation in the paper?

$$
Q \in R^{T \times d}, K \in R^{T \times d} \\
Q \cdot K^T \in R^{T \times d} \times  R^{d \times T}\\
Q \cdot K^T \in R^{T \times T} 
$$
Which is exactly the dimension of $D$

Except that does not make sense. $C$ has to be a sequence of matrices transforming $V$, as mentioned in the original post, so it needs to be of dimension $T\times d\times d$. Strictly speaking what you wrote is the correct way to do the matrix product, but I think it should be read as performing an outer product between $Q_t$ and $K_t^T$ for each $t\in [1, T]$. This is also what is done in the non-parallel case.
